# fetching event not called while using model.fetchPage?

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

i am using express, knex and bookshelf

i have a model with some properties, lets say:

```
User { 
    username(string),
    clazz(string),
    createdBy(string)(logged-in user),
    createDate(datetime) }
```

i want to fetch collection of users with respect to logged-in user(createBy, who has created the record) along with pagination.

i have tried to implement the same with following code:

```
var request = extend({ sort : 'id', order: 'asc', pageSize: 10, page: 1}, setProperties(req.query));

User.forge().orderBy(request.sort, request.order).fetchPage({
    pageSize: request.pageSize,
    page: request.page

}).then(function(results) {
    res.json({
        users: results,
        totalCount: results.pagination.rowCount
    });
});

// tried to initialize fetching event.
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('fetching', function(model, cols, options) {
            // will put extra constraint to fetch only the records created by logged-in user.
        });
    });
```

But 'fetching' event is not fired, but data is available at response.

i would really appreciate if you can help me with this, or suggest me a workaround to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake!

fetchPage calls the fetchAll, which emits the event 'fetching:collection' not 'fetching'.